# C# Core 3.1 CS1069 no se encuentra el nombre de tipo sqlconnection en el espacio de nombres system.data.sqlclient

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo mis primeras pruebas con C# Core 3.1, estoy tratando de crear una conexión con una base de datos local sql server con el siguiente código:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public class MiClase
    SqlConnection myConec= new SqlConnection();
    .
    .
    .
```

No aparece ningún error en rojo en `SqlConnection( )`, pero en la lista de errores sale el error de compilación que aparece en el encabezado de la pregunta y ademas:

> Este tipo se ha reenviado al ensamblado System.Data.SqlClient, version=4.6.1.0 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f50a3a. Puede agregar una referencia a ese ensamblado.

Ya descargué `System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.2` y estoy con VS2019 y se supone que con las últimas actualizaciones.

¿Dónde y qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola Carlos, si esta resouesta te fue util te agradeceria que la marcaras como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Microsoft** introdujo un nuevo paquete llamado **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** el cual soporta al **.Net Core** y al **.Net Framework**, se aconseja migrar a este nuevo paquete ya que va a ser el que va a recibir las nuevas características y mejoras o sea el futuro es este nuevo paquete.

**Referencias:**

**1-)** https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/

**2-)** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54472165/what-is-wrong-with-this-code-why-cant-i-use-sqlconnection

Comment: Excelente, los enlaces me han servido bastante. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola Carlos, si la respuesta te fue util puedes marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Comment: No encuentro donde marcarla cómo aceptada.

Comment: @CarlosCuenta, al lado de la respuesta que te doy te salen los botones para votar, y debajo de estos botones te sale un checkMark, para aceptar la respuesta debes clicar ese checkMark, y ademas tambien puedes darme un voto si lo deseas. Entra aqui y mira las imagenes para que veas lo que te digo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @CarlosCuenta Lado izquierdo de la pregunta, alrededor de los botones de votación, hay un check, dale click ahí.