# Conexión de C# a SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, visual

Tengo un problema al realizar mi conexión de la base de datos con C#, y  siempre lo he hecho igual, utilizando una clase para hacer la conexión.

El problema radica en que no me reconoce los comandos de SQL aunque ya he declarado la librería.

Adjunto imagen, gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Lesman, bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta elimina la imagen, y agrega tu código y el mensaje de error como texto, gracias. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Justo a tu imagen le falta lo más importante del caso!!! la parte de arriba donde están los usings

Comment: Creo que el using es `using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;` No `using System.Data.SqlClient;` como lo tienes tu. Por otro lado, creo que no es buena idea mantener la conexión abierta

Comment: @Yussef de hecho al menos c# 4.7.2(net framework ) es `System.Data.SqlClient`, en cuanto la conexión abierta en la línea que le falla solo crea el objeto para la conexión no la abre, en el código a primera vista no veo fallo en el funcionamiento. ¿Lesman cuál versión estás usando para poder intentar replicarlo?, y si es posible, ¿podrias hacer también una captura de las dependencias?

Comment: @rexxarcat la 7 -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqHHP.png

Comment: En la 7 el problema es que no esta instalado por defecto el paquete, lo tienes que instalar manualmente pero funciona igual

Comment: Eso va igual para la de `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;`

Comment: entra aki: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394423/c-core-3-1-cs1069-no-se-encuentra-el-nombre-de-tipo-sqlconnection-en-el-espacio/394472#394472